# Can you use the params keyword in a delegate?

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to define a delegate that takes a couple of dates, an unknown number of other parameters (using the `params` keyword), and that returns a list of objects:

```
Func<DateTime, DateTime, params int[], List<object>>
```

Visual Studio doesn't like the syntax which is making me think this isn't allowed.  Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't have custom attributes on a generic type argument (the CLI doesn't permit it), and the C# compiler implements the `params` keyword by emitting the `System.ParamArrayAttribute` on the relevant method parameter.

This stops you from using it with the System.Func<...> generic delegates, but you can always create your own delegate type that does use `params`.

Comment: Is possible to create Delegate with params with dynamic Expressions? Normally I would use `Expression.GetDelegateType()`, but there are no extra options for the `System.ParamArrayAttribute`.

Answer (score 54):

You can't use params for any parameter other than the last one... that's part of what it's complaining about.

You also can't use `params` in a type argument. This isn't just for delegates, but in general. For example, you can't write:

```
List<params string[]> list = new List<params string[]>();
```

You can, however, declare a *new* delegate type, like this:

```
delegate void Foo(int x, params string[] y);

...

Foo foo = SomeMethod;
foo(10, "Hi", "There");
```

Note that the method group conversion will have to match a method which takes a string array - you couldn't declare SomeMethod as:

```
void SomeMethod(int x, string a, string b)
```

and expect the above to work, for example. It would have to be:

```
void SomeMethod(int x, string[] args)
```

(Or it could use `params` itself, of course.)

Comment: Foo foo = SomeMethod(); should instead be Foo foo = SomeMethod;

Comment: @DAG: Fixed, thanks. You can always suggested edits directly of course :)

Comment: I tried! Edits have a minimum allowed length... removing two parentheses was not accepted by the system (?!)

Comment: @DAG: Ah, fair enough.