# C# Func delegate with params type

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates, lambda

How, in C#, do I have a `Func` parameter representing a method with this signature?

```
XmlNode createSection(XmlDocument doc, params XmlNode[] childNodes)
```

I tried having a parameter of type `Func<XmlDocument, params XmlNode[], XmlNode>` but, ooh, ReSharper/Visual Studio 2008 go crazy highlighting that in red.

**Update:**  okay, Googling for 'c# params func' produced no results, but 'c# params delegate' led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136470/can-you-use-the-params-keyword-in-a-delegate).  Following Jon Skeet's answer there, it looks like maybe I could create a `delegate`, say `Foo`, and then instead of having a parameter to my method of type `Func<XmlDocument, params XmlNode[], XmlNode>`, I take a parameter of type `Foo`.

Comment: @Ando:  it was highlighting so much code in red, not just the line where I had that `Func` parameter, that I couldn't even tell you all the errors it found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136470/can-you-use-the-params-keyword-in-a-delegate/1136484#1136484) to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136470/can-you-use-the-params-keyword-in-a-delegate) led me to try the following, which works:

```
protected delegate XmlNode CreateSection(XmlDocument doc,
    params XmlNode[] childNodes);

protected static void createOrUpdateSettingTree(XmlNode rootNode,
    XmlDocument doc, CreateSection createSection) { ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't have `params` in a delegate declaration. You can, however, take a single array, which would work for what you need: `Func<XmlDocument, XmlNode[], XmlNode>`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest 'params' is not allowed in this case.