# How to convert a method with an unkown number of parameters to a System.Delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

Given a method, I need to convert it to a Delegate so that I can call `.DynamicInvoke()` on it. So, for example, given a method `Foo`, I can't do `new Action<dynamic, dynamic>(Foo)` because I don't actually know that `Foo` will necessarily have 2 parameters.

So how do convert a method to a `Delegate` without knowing its parameters?

This issue is about code generation. I'm trying to write a method that generates C# code, it boils down to:

```cs
void GenerateCall(string method, params string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Delegate del_{method} = {/*Convert method to delegate here*/};");
    Console.WriteLine($"del_{method}.DynamicInvoke({string.Join(", ", args)});");
}
```

Assigning the method to a variable *is* important for what I'm doing, `Console.WriteLine($"{method}({string.Join(", ", args)})")` isn't good enough.

Comment: Have you tried `params`? You have to create your own delegate. I'm not 100% sure if this is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/1136510/495455 but its very, very similar.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Unfortunatly that's not the issue I have. It isn't that the method has a `params` parameter, but that I don't know what kinds of parameters it has.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? It doesn't matter if it doesn't work...

Comment: @JeremyThompson does that work? (See edit)

Comment: Why do you need a `Delegate` instance? Why not just get the `MethodInfo` object (via reflection) and use its `Invoke()` method? To create a delegate instance, you're going to have to select _some_ specific delegate type, which will require reflection to inspect the method's parameters and whatnot, so you might as well just use the `MethodInfo` directly.

Comment: @PeterDuniho For two reasons, first of all, I didn't know about that (thanks) and second of all, I need to be able to have Methods and actual delegates (e.g. `a=>a+1`) to be assignable to the same variable type, and `dynamic` doesn't support delegates or methods.

Comment: _"I need to be able to have Methods and actual delegates (e.g. `a=>a+1`) to be assignable to the same variable type"_ -- it's not clear what you mean by that. `a=>a+1` isn't a delegate; it's a lambda expression. Are you saying you create delegate instances from lambda expressions? How do you decide what concrete delegate type to make _those_? Bottom line: short of creating new types at run-time, you're going to have to limit yourself to some group of known delegate types, such as the set of `Func<...>` and `Action<...>` types and pick them dynamically based on `MethodInfo`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Alright, I think I see what you're saying. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

After researching this a bit, I have found that the `Expression` class has a method that will automatically select the appropriate `Func<...>` or `Action<...>` delegate type for you, and even create a new custom delegate type at runtime if none match (i.e. you have more parameters than what is available in the built-in delegate types).

With that method in hand, the rest of your question seems relatively simple to me. Here is an example of how to use `Expression.GetDelegateType()` to get the appropriate delegate type and create from that an appropriate delegate instance that can then be used to invoke the method using the supplied arguments:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();

        InvokeMethod(null, typeof(Program), "M1", "foo");
        InvokeMethod(null, typeof(Program), "M2", 17, "bar");
        InvokeMethod(program, typeof(Program), "M3", false);
    }

    static void M1(string text)
    {
        WriteLine($"M1: {text}");
    }

    static void M2(int i, string text)
    {
        WriteLine($"M2: {i}, {text}");
    }

    void M3(bool f)
    {
        WriteLine($"M3: {f}");
    }

    static void InvokeMethod(object instance, Type type, string methodName, params object[] args)
    {
        Delegate d = CreateDelegate(instance, type, methodName);

        d.DynamicInvoke(args);
    }

    static Delegate CreateDelegate(object instance, Type type, string methodName)
    {
        MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod(methodName,
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Type delegateType = Expression.GetDelegateType(mi.GetParameters()
            .Select(pi => pi.ParameterType)
            .Concat(new[] { mi.ReturnType }).ToArray());

        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, instance, mi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need.